# How do I fix this tear?

Tags: modeling

I'm working on Blender Guru's donut tutorial and ended up with these tears in the model. Why did this happen and how I can I fix it?

[image: In object Mode]

[image: In Edit Mode]

Comment: I don't think those are tears so much as they're areas where the icing is "sinking" into the donut. To fix it, all you should have to do is move the affected area upwards and outwards, so to speak. Use proportional editing to make sure the section moves smoothly together.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm!